# Replay of tests with different locators

Tags: katalon-recorder

I would compare the robustness of different locator strategies proposed by Katalon (and I have added some custom locator strategies, too).

The html output of Katalon Recorder includes both the custom locator and the default locators but only the first locator is used to locate the objects in the page.

Is there an automatic method to generate and/or replay different versions of the tests with different locator strategies?

It appears that only a manual solution involving manual modification of test cases, reload and replay of modified test cases is possible.

Comment: I know that is not the best way but you can create two test cases and use `locator 1` in `test case 1` and the `locator 2` in the `test case 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the `Smart XPath` plugin :

https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/auto-healing-smart-xpath.html#create-test-objects-by-recordingspying

Comment: No, it appears to be available only on Katalon Studio instead of Katalon Recorder